# Does "sphere" denote the surface or the entirety of a solid ball?

Tags: terminology, definition

In everyday English, the word "sphere" denotes a 3-dimensional object, including the points inside the surface and its center.

However, I get the sense that in mathematics, the sphere is used predominantly to denote the set of points on the surface of such an object. It is a 2-dimensional surface that does not include interior points. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.  In standard mathematical usage, "sphere" denotes the surface only.  The term for the interior is instead "ball" (more precisely, an "open ball" is just the interior, while a "closed ball" is the interior together with the surface).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that mathematicians have generalized the idea of a sphere to any number of dimensions, i.e., one possible way to define a 3-sphere, a higher dimensional analogue of the ordinary sphere is 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=a^2
$$
which is the set of all points equidistant from the origin in a 4 dimensional space.

One can then ask: what, fundamentally, makes something a sphere? This question turns out to be non-trivial to answer, but topologists now have an answer to that question in every dimension.